# Debounce to happen after a request has finished

Tags: node.js, debouncing

I want to create a simple `debounce` function that would take place after a given Node.js request lifecycle has finished.

Let's have this simple Node/Express app:

```
const debounce = require('debounce')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 4000

global.i = 0;

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    debounce(() => { global.i++; }, 3000, false);
    res.send(global.i.toString());
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Whenever I call `http://localhost:4000/` I get `i` as a response.

I would expect that as long as I call this endpoint under 3 seconds interval, the debounce function callback will not kick in, and `i` will be 0; and when I wait more than 3 seconds, it will run, and the next time I call the endpoint, I'd get an updated value (say `1`).

But it doesn't happen. The response ends, and the code is "dead" - the `debounce` function callback is never triggered.

**What's the right way to make things continue running in the background even after a request/response cycle has finished?**

Comment: Unrelated, but please see the bottom of [What are tags, and how should we use them](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging);. putting explicit tags in the title is redundant.

Comment: `debounce` returns a new, debounced function--you're currently throwing away that function and doing nothing.

Comment: @DaveNewton can you elaborate? i.e. what would be the right usage to achieve what I need - an execution that takes place some time after a request has ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure. This is the right way or not. But you can create debounce using timestamp. See the example below

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 4444;
global.serverInfo = {
  lastUpdate: null,
  count: 0
};

app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
  updateValue();
  res.send(global.serverInfo.count.toString());
});
const updateValue = () => {
  if (global.serverInfo.lastUpdate) clearTimeout(global.serverInfo.lastUpdate);
  global.serverInfo.lastUpdate = setTimeout(() => {
    global.serverInfo.count = global.serverInfo.count + 1;
  }, 3000);
};
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: Thanks, but this would only work if you actually call the server the 2nd time. If you only call once, the function (in this simple case adding a number to `i`) would never occur.

Comment: nice one! Nice technique.

Answer (score 1):

There is an awesome npm package available for this and many more other usecase:

https://vlio20.github.io/utils-decorators/

> npm i utils-decorators

Just use the simple decorator:

```
import { debounce } from 'utils-decorators';

  class Example1 {

    @debounce(1000)
    foo(x: number): number {
      return 42;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probebly you want debounced after send response like this code

```
const debounce = require('debounce')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 4000

global.i = 0;

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.once('end', debounce(() => { global.i++; }, 3000, false));
    res.send(global.i.toString());
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```